# Realm on Android: keep DB logic separate

Tags: android, realm

I used to work with un-auto-managed model objects that were copied from Realm. I switched to using auto-managed Realm object for my new projects and have a problem.

Where before I could keep my DB logic separate, in DAO classes, right now, the Realm code is all over my application.

Realm objects should be managed (closed) well, everywhere, on every thread, on every activity and fragment. But what I dislike most: every setter on every model object needs to be in a Realm transaction. There is Realm all over my code right now!

Did anyone find a way to keep the DB logic somewhat separate, while using auto managed Realm objects?

Comment: `Did anyone find a way to keep the DB logic somewhat separate, while using auto managed Realm objects?` only if you add synchronous callbacks, and wrap RealmResults into your own `ObservableMutableList` interface

Comment: do you know of an example of this somewhere?

Comment: No one seems to have ever done it, and I was lazy to do it. I only have an example using RxJava where I listen to changes in the Realm on a background thread and map/copy the data into immutable data objects. Doesn't scale well with very large data sets, but it seems to be what people do in general anyways. But that's not automanaged by Realm.

Comment: I wrote an article on my findings with realm auto-updated objects, including this issue. In short: separating it seems impossible. https://medium.com/@ffvanderlaan/realm-auto-updated-objects-what-you-need-to-know-b2d769d12d76

Comment: 3.2.0 will treat transient as @Ignore. Also I think separation isn't that difficult if you pass Realm to the DAO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conclusion, after a few months with Realm auto-managed objects:

Having your database code centralised, in Data Access Object (DAO) classes or the like, is hardly possible when using Realm’s auto-updated objects.

1. Every setter on every model object needs to be inside a Realm transaction block. If you use RetroLambda, the calls are relatively clean:
   realm.executeTransaction(r -> user.setFirstName(firstName));
   These blocks will be all over your project within no time. Forgetting to wrap a setter method (or a constructor call) in a transaction will crash your app. Believe me, this will happen a lot in the first weeks of adopting auto-updated objects.
2. Auto-updated objects cannot be shared across threads. The same is true for Realm instances.
   All threads, and often activities and fragments, will have to open and close Realm instances. You’ll be thinking constantly “On which thread am I?”. If you cross thread boundaries with model objects or Realm instances, you will crash your app.

More info here: https://medium.com/@ffvanderlaan/realm-auto-updated-objects-what-you-need-to-know-b2d769d12d76

and here: https://medium.com/@Zhuinden/how-to-use-realm-for-android-like-a-champ-and-how-to-tell-if-youre-doing-it-wrong-ac4f66b7f149#.gazrajqwt

Answer (score -1):

What I did was created a RealmController class that handles all of my Realm transactions, and fetches new data from the API. The skeleton for the implementation is borrowed from another SO post which I can't find right now, but you should be able to find it on Google by searching RealmController.

```js
public class RealmController {
    private static RealmController instance;
    private final Realm realm;
    private ServiceInterface restInterface;
    private final String TAG = "RealmController";

    private static boolean browseFetchAllowed = true;

    private RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
            .name("myRealm")
            .schemaVersion(0)
            .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
            .build();

    public RealmController(Application application) {
        restInterface =  ServiceGenerator.createService(ServiceInterface.class);
        realm = Realm.getInstance(config);
    }

    public void setAuthentication(String token, String uid) {
        this.restInterface = ServiceGenerator.createService(ServiceInterface.class, token, uid);
    }

    public static RealmController with(Fragment fragment) {

        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new RealmController(fragment.getActivity().getApplication());
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public static RealmController with(Activity activity) {

        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new RealmController(activity.getApplication());
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public static RealmController with(Application application) {

        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new RealmController(application);
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public RealmController getInstance() {

        return instance;
    }

    public ServiceInterface getRestInterface() {
        return restInterface;
    }

    public Realm getRealm() {
        return realm;
    }
    
    public RealmResults<MyRealmObject> getStuff() {
        return realm.where(MyRealObject.class).findAll();
    }
    
    public void setStuff(RealmList<MyRealmObject> stuff) {
        realm.beginTransaction();
        realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(stuff);
        realm.commitTransaction();
    }
    
    public void getStuffFromServer() {
        
        restInterface.getStuff().enqueue(new Callback<RealmList<MyRealmObject>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<RealmList<MyRealmObject>> call, Response<RealmList<MyRealmObject>> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    realm.beginTransaction();
                    realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(response.body);
                    realm.commitTransaction();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<RealmList<RealmAd>> call, Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Towards the bottom of the file I've added a few examples, but usage is quite simple:

```
RealmResults<MyRealmObject> results = RealmController.with(this).getStuff();
```

In terms of having the objects auto-managed, what I've been using is RealmResults, which is always auto-managed (even if you're querying for a single object). Then just add a change listener to the results of the query and voilà. Also, if you want to have auto-updating data in recyclerviews, I would recommend [RealmRecyclerView](https://github.com/thorbenprimke/realm-recyclerview).

Comment: this is what my DAO classes do, they do the queries. However, some of my model objects have lots of setter methods, setFirstName, setLastName, etc. I do not want to duplicate these all in the DAO class. But still, these setters need to be wrapped in transactions, and they're all over my code.

Comment: I see, what you could do is just have general setter methods for the whole objects -> instead of setting individual properties of your objects have setter methods for the whole object. Then just use copyToRealmOrUpdate and realm will handle updating the fields that changed.

Comment: Downvote because the  `RealmController` ignores thread confinement. Also it's from Ravi Tamada's badly written tutorial that ignores **all** good practices, while advocates bad ones. Just like here; the write is on the UI thread,

Comment: Downvote all you want, is the problem here using realm.beginTransaction()...  instead of realm.executeTransactionAsync()...? If it is, that's not really in the scope of this question and only here to provide an example, so downvoting for that reason is quite silly. Are there some other bad practices in use here?

Comment: Also, if you don't mind linking to the tutorial, would be interested in seeing what kinds of bad practices he is advocating there.

Comment: At first glance: I don't see any realm.close() call in this class. Also, this can only be used single threaded?

Comment: Technically you shouldn't even need `executeTranasctionAsync()`. You should execute the network operation on a background thread, and write it into a Realm that you open and close on the background thread. You listen for changes on the UI thread using `RealmChangeListener`. Treat every `RealmResults<T>` like a Subscription.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but afaik executeTransaction() does the work in a background thread, as well as Retrofit's ```call.enqueue(...)``` so is it really necessary to start a new thread in addition to those? Or is there something I'm not understanding here?

Comment: `call.enqueue` runs on a background thread, and the callback is executed on the UI thread. Then, `realm.executeTransaction()` runs a *synchronous* write transaction on the UI thread. So you *could* use `executeTransactionAsync()`, except it doesn't make sense to jump between bg thread => UI thread => bg thread => UI thread. As for bad practices in the tutorial, I [**have an entire article about it**](https://medium.com/@Zhuinden/how-to-use-realm-for-android-like-a-champ-and-how-to-tell-if-youre-doing-it-wrong-ac4f66b7f149).